# Implementing a Game start / Game Over / restart steps to a basic css canvas game

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas

So I'm trying to create a basic css game. I was able to get it to work without any additional screens (the game would just start the moment the HTML it's written on is opened), and now I'm trying to add additional functionality (the first screen in the canvas would have a button to start the game and after the game is over, there would be a new screen on the canvas with a "Try again" -button) to it.

I thought I could do it by making the initialization of the game board (that used to be in a global scope / outside of any functions) a "GameStart()" -function, but for some reason it's not quite working.

The code is properly calling for my GameStart() -function (tested it out by placing alerts on key spots), but I can't get it to call my draw() -function which would start the actual game and loop.

Here's my code, though I've taken the liberty to not include the functions related to how the game works (the functions draw() uses) since they'd just act as spam here.

Edit:
To clarify, what I'm trying to ask is if it's possible to incorporate different screens for a canvas game this way or is there a "proper" way that's completely different from this?

```
<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
var ctx = canvas. getContext("2d");


function GameStart()
{
    // clear previous canvas
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // ball variables here
    var dx = 0;
    var dy = 0;
    var ballRadius = 7;
    var x = canvas.width/2;
    var y = canvas.height/2;

    // paddle variables here
    var paddleHeight = 10;
    var paddleWidth = 125;
    var paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
    var rightbutton = false;
    var leftbutton = false;

    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);

    // destroyable blockfields here
    var brickRowCount = 6;
    var brickColumnCount = 20;
    var brickWidth = 45;
    var brickHeight = 45;
    var brickPadding = 0;
    var brickOffsetTop = 30;
    var brickOffsetLeft = 30;
    var bricks=[];

    for(c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) 
    {
        bricks[c] = [];
        for(r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) 
        {
            bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0, status: 1 };
        }
    }

    // player here
    var score = 0;
    var lives = 3;
    var destroyed = 0;
    var dscore = 1;
    var endscore = 0;
    draw();
}
```

... there's a bunch of functions related to the game between here, but they should not be the cause of the problem since they worked fine when I was not trying to add the "GameStart()" -function ...

```
function draw() {
    alert("Drawing");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawBall();
    drawPaddle();
    collisionDetection();
    drawBricks();
    drawScore();
    drawLives();
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    if (dy < 2 && dy >= 0)
    {
        dy += 0.05;
    }
    if (score >  0)
    {
        score=score-dscore;
    }
    if(rightbutton && paddleX < canvas.width-paddleWidth)
    {
        paddleX +=5;
    }
    else if(leftbutton && paddleX > 0)
    {
        paddleX -=5;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
</script>
```

The only thing I changed about the code is that I tied the actions that weren't inside any functions prior to this into the GameStart() -function and moved draw() -call from the end of the script into the GameStart() -function and added GameStart() -function call to the end of the script

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
  
  /*
   This here is a simple 'module pattern', it's a
   function that is immiediately invoked.
   so the variable stateManager is having the function's
   return object assigned to it.
   
   JS has a concept called 'closures'
   In a nutshell variables created inside this function
   when used by methods in stateManager won't be forgotten
   
   This effectively allows us to create what is called a namespace
   in other languages, private scope.
   
   e.g.
   
   var module = (function() {
    
    "use strict";
    This is a hint for the JS engine to enforce strict mode
    It just means to enforce better syntax rules
    
    e.g. value = 10; instead of var value = 10; will create an error.
   
    var value = 10;
   
    return {
     getValue: function() {
      return value;
     }
    };
   
   })();
   
   module.getValue(); <- returns 10
  */
  
  // Encapsulates some simple UI for an individual state
  var UI = (function() {
  
   function UI() {
    this.labels = [];
    this.buttons = [];
    this.fontHeight = 0;
   }
   
   UI.prototype = {
    createLabel: function(labelID,labelText,x,y,FG,BG) {
     var label = {
      ID: labelID || "" + this.labels.length,
      text: labelText || "",
      x: x || 0,
      y: y || 0,
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      FG: FG || "black",
      BG: BG || "black"
     };
     
     this.labels[labelID] = label;
     this.labels.push(label);
    },
    
    createButton: function(buttonID,buttonText,x,y,width,height,FG,BG,pressedBG,callback) {
     var button = {
      ID: buttonID || "" + this.buttons.length,
      text: buttonText || "",
      x: x || 0,
      y: y || 0,
      width: width || 0,
      height: height || 0,
      FG: FG || "black",
      BG: BG || "black",
      pressedBG: pressedBG || "black",
      callback: callback || function() {},
      isPressed: false
     };
     
     this.buttons[buttonID] = button;
     this.buttons.push(button);
    },
    
    setLabelText(labelID,newText) {
     var label = this.labels[labelID];
     
     if (label) {
      label.text = newText;
      label.width = this.ctx.measureText(newText).width + 4;
      label.height = this.fontHeight;
     }
    },
    
    setButtonText(buttonID,newText) {
     var button = this.buttons[buttonID];
     
     if (button) {
      button.text = newText;
     }
    },
    
    setFont: function(ctx,newFont,fontSize) {
     this.ctx = ctx;
     ctx.font = (fontSize|0) + "px " + (newFont || "Arial");
     this.fontHeight = fontSize;
    
     for (var i = 0; i < this.labels.length; ++i) {
      var label = this.labels[i];
      
      label.width = ctx.measureText(label.text).width + 4;
      label.height = fontSize * 1.2;
     }
    },
    
    onmousedown: function(x,y) {
     for (var i = 0; i < this.buttons.length; ++i) {
      var button = this.buttons[i];
      var isOverlapping = x > button.x && x < button.x + button.width
           && y > button.y && y < button.y + button.height;
      
      if (isOverlapping) {
       button.isPressed = true;
       return;
      }
     }
    },
    
    onmouseup: function(x,y) {
     for (var i = 0; i < this.buttons.length; ++i) {
      var button = this.buttons[i];
      var isOverlapping = x > button.x && x < button.x + button.width
           && y > button.y && y < button.y + button.height;
      
      if (isOverlapping && button.isPressed) {
       button.isPressed = false;
       button.callback();
       return;
      }
      
      button.isPressed = false;
     }
    },
    
    render: function(ctx) {
     for (var i = 0; i < this.labels.length; ++i) {
      var label = this.labels[i];
      
      ctx.fillStyle = label.BG;
      ctx.fillRect(
       label.x - label.width * 0.5,
       label.y - label.height  * 0.5 - this.fontHeight * 0.25,
       label.width,
       label.height
      );
      
      ctx.fillStyle = label.FG;
      ctx.fillText(label.text,label.x,label.y);
     }
     
     for (var i = 0; i < this.buttons.length; ++i) {
      var button = this.buttons[i];
      
      ctx.fillStyle = button.isPressed ? button.pressedBG : button.BG;
      ctx.fillRect(
       button.x,
       button.y,
       button.width,
       button.height
      );
      
      ctx.fillStyle = button.FG;
      ctx.fillText(
       button.text,
       button.x + button.width * 0.5,
       button.y + button.height * 0.5 + this.fontHeight * 0.25
      );
     }
    }
   };
   
   return UI;
  
  }());
  
  // Use to create and switch between different game screens
  var state = (function() {
   
   "use strict";
   
   var bgColour = "#444444";
   var canvasWidth = 0;
   var canvasHeight = 0;
   var canvas = null;
   var ctx = null;
   var bounds = null;
   
   var hasStarted = false;
   var currentState = null;
   var stateMap = {}; // Stores all states
   var stateStack = []; // Holds trace of states that have been pushed on each other
  
   function onmousemoved(e) {   
    var x = e.clientX - bounds.left;
    var y = e.clientY - bounds.top;
   
    if (currentState.onmousemoved) {
     currentState.onmousemoved(x,y);
    }
    
    if (e.button === 1 && currentState.ui) {
     ui.onmousedown(x,y);
    }
   }
  
   function onmousedown(e) {
    var x = e.clientX - bounds.left;
    var y = e.clientY - bounds.top;
    var b = e.button;
    
    if (currentState.onmousedown) {
     currentState.onmousedown(x,y,b);
    }
    
    if (currentState.ui) {
     currentState.ui.onmousedown(x,y);
    }
   }
   
   function onmouseup(e) {
    var x = e.clientX - bounds.left;
    var y = e.clientY - bounds.top;
    var b = e.button;
    
    if (currentState.onmouseup) {
     currentState.onmousemoved(x,y,b);
    }
    
    if (currentState.ui) {
     currentState.ui.onmouseup(x,y);
    }
   }
  
   function onkeydown(e) {
    if (currentState.onkeydown) {
     currentState.onkeydown(e);
    }
   }
   
   function onkeyup(e) {
    if (currentState.onkeyup) {
     currentState.onkeyup(e);
    }
   }
   
   function loop() {
    if (currentState.ontick) {
     currentState.ontick();
    }
    
    ctx.fillStyle = bgColour;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < stateStack.length; ++i) {
     var state = stateStack[i];
     
     if (state.onrender) {
      state.onrender(ctx);
     }
     
     if (state.ui) {
      state.ui.render(ctx);
     }
    }
    
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
   }
  
   function start() {
    for (var stateID in stateMap) {
     var state = stateMap[stateID];
     
     if (state.oncreate) { 
      state.oncreate();
      
      if (state.ui) {
       state.ui.setFont(ctx,"Courier New",14);
      }
     }
    }
    
    addEventListener("mousemoved",onmousemoved);
    addEventListener("mousedown",onmousedown);
    addEventListener("mouseup",onmouseup);
    addEventListener("keydown",onkeydown);
    addEventListener("keyup",onkeyup);
   
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
   }
  
   return {
    setCanvas: function(_canvas,_width,_height) {
     canvas = _canvas;
     canvasWidth = _width;
     canvasHeight = _height;
     
     canvas.width = canvasWidth;
     canvas.height = canvasHeight;
     ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     ctx.textAlign = "center";
     bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    },
    
    setBackground: function(r,g,b) {
     bgColour = "#" + (r|0).toString(16) + (g|0).toString(16) + (b|0).toString(16);
    },
   
    // Add a new state
    define: function(stateID,newState) {
     stateMap[stateID] = newState;
    },
    
    // Manually switch the current state (clears the stack)
    switch: function(stateID) {
     var state = stateMap[stateID];
     
     if (state) {
      for (var i = 0; i < stateStack.length; ++i) {
       var stackedState = stateStack[i];
       
       if (stackedState.onend) {
        stackedState.onend();
       }
      }
     
      stateStack.length = 1;
      stateStack[0] = state;
      currentState = state;
      
      if (currentState.onstart) {
       currentState.onstart();
      }
      
      if (!hasStarted) {
       hasStarted = true;
       start();
      }
     }
    },
    
    // add/remove from the state stack
    push: function(stateID) {
     var state = stateMap[stateID];
     
     if (state && stateStack.indexOf(state) === -1) {
      stateStack.push(state);
      
      if (hasStarted && currentState.onpause) {
       currentState.onpause();
      }
      
      currentState = stateStack[stateStack.length - 1];
      
      if (currentState.onstart) {
       currentState.onstart();
      }
      
      if (!hasStarted) {
       hasStarted = true;
       start();
      }
     }
    },
    
    pop: function() {
     if (stateStack.length > 1) {
      stateStack.pop();
      
      if (currentState.onend) {
       currentState.onend();
      }
      
      currentState = stateStack[stateStack.length - 1];
      
      if (currentState.onresume) {
       currentState.onresume();
      }
     }
    }
   };
  
  })();
  
  </script>
  
  <script type="application/javascript">
  
   /*
    This is similar to the module pattern above but
    it's strictly being used to provide a private scope
   */
   void function() {
   
    "use strict";
    
    var canvasWidth = 180;
    var canvasHeight = 160;
    
    // Define game screens
    state.define("mainMenu",{
     oncreate: function() {
      var ui = new UI();
      
      ui.createLabel(
       "mainMenuLabel", // id
       "Main Menu", // text
       90, // x
       20, // y
       "white", // text colour
       "darkgreen" // background colour
      );
      
      ui.createButton(
       "startGameButton", // id
       "Start Game", // text
       45, // x
       55, // y
       90, // width
       30, // height
       "white", // text colour
       "#222222", // background colour
       "#555555", // background colour (when clicked on)
       function() { // function to run when clicked
        state.switch("gameState");
       }
      );
      
      ui.createButton(
       "openOptionsButton",
       "Options",
       45,
       95,
       90,
       30,
       "white",
       "#222222",
       "#555555",
       function() {
        state.switch("optionsMenu");
       }
      );
      
      this.ui = ui;
     },
    });
    
    var editingKey = '';
    var upControl = 'w';
    var downControl = 's';
    var leftControl = 'a';
    var rightControl = 'd';
    
    state.define("optionsMenu",{
     oncreate: function() {
      var ui = new UI();
      
      ui.createLabel(
       "optionsMenuLabel",
       "Options Menu",
       90,
       20,
       "white",
       "darkgreen"
      );
      
      ui.createButton(
       "upButton",
       "Up: '" + upControl + "'",
       45,
       30,
       90,
       20,
       "white",
       "#222222",
       "#555555",
       function() {
        editingKey = "up";
        ui.setButtonText("upButton","Up: '?'");
        ui.setButtonText("downButton","Down: '" + downControl + "'");
        ui.setButtonText("leftButton","Left: '" + leftControl + "'");
        ui.setButtonText("rightButton","Right: '" + rightControl + "'");
       }
      );
      
      ui.createButton(
       "downButton",
       "Down: '" + downControl + "'",
       45,
       55,
       90,
       20,
       "white",
       "#222222",
       "#555555",
       function() {
        editingKey = "down";
        ui.setButtonText("upButton","Up: '" + upControl + "'");
        ui.setButtonText("downButton","Down: '?'");
        ui.setButtonText("leftButton","Left: '" + leftControl + "'");
        ui.setButtonText("rightButton","Right: '" + rightControl + "'");
       }
      );
      
      ui.createButton(
       "leftButton",
       "Left: '" + leftControl + "'",
       45,
       80,
       90,
       20,
       "white",
       "#222222",
       "#555555",
       function() {
        editingKey = "left";
        ui.setButtonText("upButton","Up: '" + upControl + "'");
        ui.setButtonText("downButton","Down: '" + downControl + "'");
        ui.setButtonText("leftButton","Left: '?'");
        ui.setButtonText("rightButton","Right: '" + rightControl + "'");
       }
      );
      
      ui.createButton(
       "rightButton",
       "Right: '" + rightControl + "'",
       45,
       105,
       90,
       20,
       "white",
       "#222222",
       "#555555",
       function() {
        editingKey = "right";
        ui.setButtonText("upButton","Up: '" + upControl + "'");
        ui.setButtonText("downButton","Down: '" + downControl + "'");
        ui.setButtonText("leftButton","Left: '" + leftControl + "'");
        ui.setButtonText("rightButton","Right: '?'");
       }
      );
      
      ui.createButton(
       "backButton",
       "Back",
       68.5,
       135,
       45,
       15,
       "white",
       "#222222",
       "#555555",
       function() {
        ui.setButtonText("upButton","Up: '" + upControl + "'");
        ui.setButtonText("downButton","Down: '" + downControl + "'");
        ui.setButtonText("leftButton","Left: '" + leftControl + "'");
        ui.setButtonText("rightButton","Right: '" + rightControl + "'");
        state.switch("mainMenu");
       }
      );
      
      this.ui = ui;
     },
     
     onkeydown: function(e) {
      switch(editingKey) {
       case "up": {
        editingKey = "";
        upControl = e.key;
        this.ui.setButtonText("upButton","Up: '" + upControl + "'");
       } break;
       
       case "down": {
        editingKey = "";
        downControl = e.key;
        this.ui.setButtonText("downButton","Down: '" + downControl + "'");
       } break;
       
       case "left": {
        editingKey = "";
        leftControl = e.key;
        this.ui.setButtonText("leftButton","Left: '" + leftControl + "'");
       } break;
       
       case "right": {
        editingKey = "";
        rightControl = e.key;
        this.ui.setButtonText("rightButton","Right: '" + rightControl + "'");
       } break;
      }
     }
    });
    
    var player = {
     x: 90,
     y: 80,
     speed: 1.0,
     radius: 10,
     
     up: false,
     down: false,
     left: false,
     right: false,
     
     tick: function() {
      if (this.up) { this.y -= this.speed; }
      if (this.down) { this.y += this.speed; }
      if (this.left) { this.x -= this.speed; }
      if (this.right) { this.x += this.speed; }
     },
     
     render: function(ctx) {
      ctx.fillStyle = "darkred";
      ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
      ctx.lineWidth = 3;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0.0,2.0*Math.PI,false);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
     }
    };
    
    state.define("gameState",{
     oncreate: function() {
      var ui = new UI();
      
      ui.createButton(
       "backButton",
       "Quit",
       canvasWidth - 55,
       10,
       45,
       15,
       "white",
       "#222222",
       "#555555",
       function() {
        state.switch("mainMenu");
       }
      );
      
      this.ui = ui;
     },
     
     onkeydown: function(e) {
      switch(e.key) {
       case upControl: player.up = true; break;
       case downControl: player.down = true; break;
       case leftControl: player.left = true; break;
       case rightControl: player.right = true; break;
      }
     },
     
     onkeyup: function(e) {
      switch(e.key) {
       case upControl: player.up = false; break;
       case downControl: player.down = false; break;
       case leftControl: player.left = false; break;
       case rightControl: player.right = false; break;
      }
     },
     
     ontick: function() {
      player.tick();
     },
     
     onrender: function(ctx) {
      ctx.fillStyle = "darkblue";
      ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
      
      player.render(ctx);
     }
    });
    
    /*
     This function runs when the page
     finishes loading, it isn't essential
     but I like to use it as a 'main method'/entry point
    */
    window.onload = function() {
     state.setCanvas(document.getElementById("canvas"),canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
     state.switch("mainMenu");
    }
   
   }();
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just use my code as an example, if you want to make a game with multiple states I'd recommend Phaser.